# When I use chromeview I got some error

Tags: android

When I use chromeview I got some error like below:

```
E/chromium(1060): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(127)] No suitable EGL configs found.
E/chromium(1060): [ERROR:gl_surface_android.cc(30)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
E/chromium(1060): [ERROR:sys_info_android.cc(105)] Can't parse dalvik.vm.heapgrowthlimit: 
E/chromium(1060): [ERROR:context_group.cc(97)] ContextGroup::Initialize failed because maximum renderbuffer size too small.
E/chromium(1060): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2199)] GpuScheduler::InitializeCommon failed because group failed to initialize.
E/chromium(1060): [ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(167)] Failed to initialize command buffer service.
E/chromium(1060): [ERROR:context_group.cc(97)] ContextGroup::Initialize failed because maximum renderbuffer size too small.
E/chromium(1060): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2199)] GpuScheduler::InitializeCommon failed because group failed to initialize.
E/chromium(1060): [ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(167)] Failed to initialize command buffer service.
E/chromium(1060): [ERROR:context_group.cc(97)] ContextGroup::Initialize failed because maximum renderbuffer size too small.
E/chromium(1060): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2199)] GpuScheduler::InitializeCommon failed because group failed to initialize.
E/chromium(1060): [ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(167)] Failed to initialize command buffer service.
E/chromium(1060): [ERROR:context_group.cc(97)] ContextGroup::Initialize failed because maximum renderbuffer size too small.
E/chromium(1060): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2199)] GpuScheduler::InitializeCommon failed because group failed to initialize.
E/chromium(1060): [ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(167)] Failed to initialize command buffer service.
```

Comment: Are you using Genymotion emulator? I sometimes get similar error with that, and restarting the emulator always helps.

Comment: thanks for your help,yes i used emulator and had restarted a few times,still got the error.have no ideal what's the reson,will try again.

Comment: Did it ever worked on the emulator for you? It is clearly a problem about OpenGL support missing (because of the emulator).

Comment: Are you using the latest version of emulator? It looks like your emulator doesn't support OpenGL ES 2.0. As far as I know, new emulators support it. Also make sure you check "Use host GPU" in the emulator setup window.

Comment: Thank you very much,my emulator not the latest version and had not checked "Use host GPU",will try it.